# Create repository from existing source code archives

Tags: git, svn, import

I have several (50+) zip archives of various revisions of a project.  I would like to create a repository from these archives (most likely git or svn).  Obviously I could unzip the latest archive and have that be my initial point, but I would like to retain the code history by importing all previous revisions of my archives.

Is there a clean way to accomplish this task?

Comment: So start with the earliest version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert release archives to git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46268631/how-to-convert-release-archives-to-git-repo)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming Subversion, as I am not familiar with git. I also don’t often use the Subversion command line, which you may want to with so many archives to import, so my instructions are a little high-level. I expect that many considerations would apply to other version control systems.

#### New repository?

You do not need to create a new repository; you can use a new directory in an existing or a new repository. An advantage to a new repository would be that you can do a dry run and then start again from scratch; you could even practise on a scratch repository and then import into an existing repository. What you don’t want to do is import them, delete them and report them again, as that wastes space in the repository: the trial versions are still stored, but serve no useful purpose.

#### Branching in your versions?

Before starting you might consider whether your archives represent a purely linear sequence, or whether there are maintenance `branches`, release `tags` and a mainline `trunk` that would find into the [conventional Subversion structure](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.layout) (see also [branch/merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html)) or some modification of it; I describe that case later.

#### Log messages

I hope you will be able to give each version a log message that you and any colleagues will find helpful, but if they are not readily available, you can import everything with some such simple text as `imported from <archive-name>`, and modify the messages later, as long as the [pre-revprop-change hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-revprop-change.html) has been implemented to permit changes to the log messages.

#### Creating the first version

I would start by creating the directory in the repository and then do a `checkout`; if you [`import`](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-import.html) the directory you will have to check it out again anyway, as far as I can see. So `checkout` your empty directory as a new Working Copy.
Then start with your **oldest** archive, unzip it into the Working Copy, `add` all the files (or all those you want) and do your first `commit`.

#### Adding subsequent versions

For each successive archive, you must reproduce the changes from the previous version. If you just unpack it into the Working Copy, any deleted files will still be there, which is not what you want, and may be hard to remove automatically, though you may be able to `delete` them on the basis of file dates. But Subversion won’t mind if you empty the Working Copy (apart from the `.svn` directory) “behind its back”, i.e. directly in the file system, and then unpack your next archive into it. When the files reappear, Subversion will just regard them as new versions. What you need to do is to `delete` (from Subversion) all the files that are missing, and to `add` the ones that are new  (or to `rename` or `copy` if needed: *see next section*). With Tortoise adding and deleting are fairly straightforward (make sure the `commit` dialogue is showing unversioned files), but with more a large number of versions and/or a large codebase you may well want to automate it. I don’t know the `svn` commands for that offhand, you will need to research them if no-one else comes up with them; you might need to process the output of `svn status` to generate the required operations.

#### Renames and copies

What could be more problematic is copied and/or renamed files or directories: that will have to be dealt with manually, unless there is some extra information you can use.
On the other hand, you may find it acceptable not to worry about this: in this case a renamed or copied file will appear to have been added out if the blue at the same time that an apparently unrelated file was deleted (in the case of a rename), the Subversion log will not show you its complete history, and you will not be readily able to look at changes between versions across a rename/copy.

#### Creating branches

If a new archive is for a new branch, you should create the branch in the repository with `copy`, check it out to a different Working Copy and then apply the next archive to that Working Copy as previously described.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create a git repository.  Clone the repository,  addyour oldest, and then commit the files. Add another set of files and repeat the procedure.